# Why does south use migration files?

Tags: python, django, database-migration, django-south, merge-conflict-resolution

I'm working on a Django app with one other developer.  I love Django so far.

But I picked up a copy of south in order to be able to modify models.py during development, and now we're having migration merge conflicts all the time.

Yup, I already got the memo:

```
The important message here is that South is no substitute for team coordination - in fact, most 
of the features are there purely to warn you that you haven’t coordinated, and the simple merging 
on offer is only there for the easy cases. Make sure your team know who is working on what, so they 
don’t write migrations that affect the same parts of the DB at the same time.
```

But I am confused as to why migration files exist at all?  If models.py is the authoritative word on db schema, what do migration files give me?  Hopefully this will help me understand how to use south better.

Comment: from django documentation:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/ Migrations are Django’s way of propagating changes you make to your models (adding a field, deleting a model, etc.) into your database schema. They’re designed to be mostly automatic, but you’ll need to know when to make migrations, when to run them, and the common problems you might run into. although I copied it from django 1.7 documentation, but bottom line is same about migration for both south and django-migration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about your data, then you don't need migration files, nor even South FWIW - you could just wipe out your tables and re-run a `manage.py syncdb`. The point here is to allow for data migrations too, which has proven to be a very useful feature once you're in production and have a lot of real data you care about.

Suppose you have a field you want to split in two or move to another model etc... If you don't want to loose your data, you need a three-steps process:

1. add the new field(s)
2. move your data to the new field(s)
3. remove the old field.

This translates into

1. a first schema migration
2. a data migration
3. a second schemamigration

NB : you can of course put it all into a single migration file (and it's obviously the cleanest solution since it makes your migration atomic), but it's easier to use the automatic schema migration generation for 1. and 3.

To make a long story short: "migration files" are actually migration *scripts*, which is what you'd need to write for any real-life production project. South mainly provides a supporting framework (migration scripts can be really tricky) and a very handy schema migrations generator that makes your life easier for one of the most common use case (non-destructive schema changes).

Comment: Ok, this is making sense.  So, early in the app development when models are a bit volatile and there is no production server, there's not much point in keeping migrations.  

But once we have valuable data in a production server, any changes to db schema should be covered by a migration, which can then be applied to the production server to keep valuable data in tact.

Comment: Migrations are useful for development too. Migrations are to your schema (and data) what git (or any other source code versionning system) is to your code base - it lets you track changes and rollback to a previous version of the schema. From experience, this is really worth the (slight) pain of having to fix a couple merge conflicts here and then, and way better than having to manually wipe the db - re-syncdb -enter new data each time you change your models (and let's not talk about manually maintaining fixtures for all your test data).

Answer (score 0):

Migration files keep the history of your models and are best used with versioning systems (like SVN):

1. you change models.py, then make a migration and it becomes part of your project
2. other team members take the migration and run it; then they make their own changes to models.py and create the proper migration

More: migrations files are used also for data migrations: you can edit them to tell how to populate new fields or how to deal with removed ones...

Comment: Couldn't I argue that my models.py keeps the history of my models, since it is versioned?

Comment: It is not the same: versioning takes snapshots of your code; migrations contain the instructions to go from one snapshot to the next one

Comment: Well, by definition models.py does keep a history of my models, *and yet* it's not the same as migrations.  So migrations must add something extra.  Given some current schema, and an altered models.py, the migration implied is ambiguous for at least two reasons.  As you allude, there's data: what to do for records with new (or deleted) non-null fields.  But also, two sequences of migrations that start and end with the same models.py can give different schemas because of different column ordering. Migrations remove that ambiguity.  If that weren't the case, they could be generated on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

Having migration files allows you to part your database development into stages. Keeps the track of changes in database allowing to go back or forth in history.

It is useful for:

- debugging
- staging your application (e.g. developer's server, test server and production)
- allows you to apply changes with some automation tools (fabric)

Of course it is possible to done it other ways, but then other problems may occur (like reseting and filling whole database)

Comment: I'm not totally convinced:  I could develop my database in stages without south -- since models.py versioning keeps this.  I realize that south isn't the only way, but want to better understand what it adds.

Comment: Your second point seems promising -- maybe elaborate that by describing a workflow in which south is used for the management of dev / test / and production server db schemas.

Comment: @burnodesthuilliers I wish!  At the moment, pretty much every branch we make is developping some aspect of models, and this often means modifying the same models concurrently.  We've settled on a workflow where we only ever commit migrations on the trunk.  We do use migration on branches, of course, but don't actually commit them.  When merging a branch into tho trunk, we re-create the migrations on the trunk and commit that.  This makes a single linear, merge-free migration history.